# How to calculate dB from StreamVolumeEventArgs.MaxSampleValues of NAudio?

Tags: c#, naudio

I am trying to implement a volume meter to help users select their microphone using [NAudio](https://naudio.codeplex.com/). I need to do my best to weed out devices that just have background noise and insure I show something when they talk.

We are currently using version 1.7.3 within a Unity3D application so none of the `MMDevice` related approaches are available as they crash.

I am using a `WaveInEvent` that I feed into a `WaveInProvider` that I subsequently feed to a `SampleChannel`. I feed the `SampleChannel` into a `MeteringSampleProvider` which I have subscribed to the `StreamVolume` event.

In my `OnPostVolumeMeter` event handler when I receive the `StreamVolumeEventArgs` (I named the parameter `e`) I'm wondering how to calculate decibels. I have seen plenty of examples that fish out the peak volume (or sometimes it seems to be referred to as an amplitude) from `e.MaxSampleValues[0]`. Some examples check whether it is a stereo signal and will grab the max between `e.MaxSampleValues[0]` or `e.MaxSampleValues[1]`.

Anyway, what are the values of this number? Is it a percentage? They are relatively small decimals (10^-3 or 10^-4) when I hillbilly debug to the console.

Is the calculation something like,

```
 var peak = e.MaxSampleValues[0];
 if (e.MaxSampleValues.Length > 1)
 {
     peak = Mathf.Max(e.MaxSampleValues[0], e.MaxSampleValues[1]);
 }
 var dB = Mathf.Max(20.0f*Mathf.Log10(peak), -96.0f);
```

or do I need to divide peak by 32768.0? As in,

```
var dB = Mathf.Max(20.0f*Mathf.Log10(peak/32768.0f), -96.0f);
```

Is this approach totally incorrect and I need to collect a buffer of samples that I do an RMS sort of calculation where I calculate the square root of the sum of the averages divided by the number of samples all divided by 32768 and feed that into the Log10?

I've seen several references to look at the AudioPlaybackPanel of the NAudioDemo and it sets the volumeMeter Amplitude to be the values of `e.MaxSampleValues[0]` and `e.MaxSampleValues[1]`

Comment: I was also looking at this [1] Wikipedia article and now I wonder is the value I get in e.MaxSampleValues[] an "amplitude ratio"?

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel#Absolute_measurements

Answer (score 0):

looking at the date of your post this is probably a solved issue for you but of the benefit of others here goes.

Audio signals swing between negative and positive values in a wave. The frequency of the swing and the Amplitude or height of the swing effect what you hear.

You are correct in saying you are looking for the amplitude to see if audio is present.

For a meter as the sample rate is much higher than the refresh rate of any meter you are likely to display, you will need to either record the peak using math.max or do an average over a number of samples. In your case either would work, unless you are trying to show an accurate meter in bdFS the db calculation would not be needed.

In apps where I have been looking to trigger things based on the presence of audio or lack their of. I normally convert the samples to a float this will give you a range between 0 and 1 and then pick a threshold say 0.2 and say if any sample is above that we have audio.

a float also provides a nice indicative meter for display. Note if your app was for a pro audio application and you were asking about accurate metering my answer would be totally different.